# Insert only time data in timestamp without time zone column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

The data type of a column in the PostgreSQL database(v 14) table, is timestamp without time zone.

I have to import exported data from DB2 database in this table. The value is 39:40.7. It doesn't contain the date value.

Trying to import data using pgAdmin fails as it complains about invalid data.

My restrictions being I cannot change the data type of the column or the data.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds a bit like "I have a cruise ship and a shoe box. I have to put the cruise ship into the shoe box. I cannot change the cruise ship not the shoe box.". Seriously, how is "39:40.7" representing a point in time? That won't fit (directly). If you'd know *how* it encodes a point in time, maybe someone can help you get a translation into a more common representation that is understood by Postgres. Maybe it's 39 minutes, 40.7 seconds from 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 or something similar?

Comment: Postgres supports a [TIME](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) data type. Perhaps that is what you need as it does not have the date component.

Comment: thanks folks for your comments. it helped as was able to change  the format in the data provided.